# Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC while setting the excel cell color using interop in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel-interop

I am getting this error "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC" while setting up the excel cell color through interop in VB.NET

Please note that I have almost gone through every post on this error on stack overflow and other forums and did whatever was mentioned there as a solution but still PROBLEM IS UNSOLVED.

Here is my code:

```
Imports excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

.
.
.

```
Dim ExcelApp As excel.Application = Nothing
Dim ExcelWorkBook As excel.Workbook = Nothing
Dim ExcelWorkSheet As excel.Worksheet = Nothing
Dim Workbooks As excel.Workbooks = Nothing


Try

    ExcelApp = New excel.Application
    Workbooks = ExcelApp.Workbooks
    ExcelWorkBook = Workbooks.Open("F:\ImpensaData.xlsx")
    ExcelWorkSheet = ExcelWorkBook.Sheets(1)

    ''''GETTING EXCEPTION ON THIS LINE
    ExcelWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1).interior.color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red)

    ExcelWorkBook.Save()

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
Finally
    ExcelWorkBook.Close()
    Workbooks.Close()
    ExcelApp.Quit()
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelWorkSheet)
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelWorkBook)
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Workbooks)
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelApp)
    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()

End Try
```

Please let me know if any more information is available on this issue. I am stuck on this issue since last 2 weeks.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Can you verify your Excel document has a sheet at index 1?

Comment: By the way, try on a new (blank) Excel document. If it works, there is a problem with your Excel document.

Comment: yes, code is working with new excel. meaning problem with my excel.

Comment: Try repairing the document through excel https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-a-corrupted-workbook-153a45f4-6cab-44b1-93ca-801ddcd4ea53